# Menu fading out of a navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, menu, uinavigationbar

I want to have a menu in views and tableviews where I have a navigationbar in my iphone-app. The menu should fade in from above, when clicking on the menu-button on the navigationbar.

Currently I have a view with buttons as a menu and animate them in an out using menus y-position. I added the menu inside my current viewvontrollers view, but I get into trouble, when my menu is above a table-section.

My idea is to cutomize the navigationbar and set a view into it as the parentview for my menu. Is this a good idea? The navigationbar should alway be visible, even while the menu fades in.

Are there any example on the web, I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick and dirty way would probably be to grow the bounds (height) of the `UINavigationBar` and then use `[Navbar addSubview:]` to add your custom view.

However, this probably won't look good and might fly in the face of Apple's Human Interface Guidelines. If you want to use a menu, I would use something close to the `UIPopover` class on the iPad. A couple GitHub projects exist already to recreate the class on the iPhone - https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover

Edit: Thought of something else: You might want to look into [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006801). It sounds like exactly what you want to do, except comes out of the bottom instead of from the Navigation Bar.